# Работа с ошибками в С++. Деление на ноль

Tags: c++, исключения, обработка-ошибок

Пишу свой проект в учебных целях для работы с обыкновенными дробями.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "simple_math.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace simple_math;

int main()
{
    cout << fraction(1, 2) + fraction(1, 3); // в результате выводит "5 / 6"
    return 0;
}
```

Что если знаменатель какой-то дроби будет равен нулю. Понятно, что нужно выкинуть ошибку, но как это сделать?

```
if(b == 0)
{
    // ОШИБКА!
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вы хотите работать по C++'ному, то нужно генерировать исключение. Можно собственного типа, можно наследовать от стандартного `exception` - это уже вопрос стиля и предпочтений. Примерно так -

```
class DivideByZero {};

...

if (b == 0) throw DivideByZero();

...

try {

    cout << fraction(1, 2) + fraction(1, 3); // в результате выводит "5 / 6"
} catch(DivideByZero&)
{
    cerr << "Divide by zero error!\n"
}
```

Или, если воспользоваться стандартным - думаю, тут правильнее `invalid_argument` - то

```
if (b == 0) throw invalid_argument("Divide by zero error in fraction!");

...

try {

    cout << fraction(1, 2) + fraction(1, 3); // в результате выводит "5 / 6"
} catch(exception&e)
{
    cerr << e.what() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Если вас волнует производительность - учтите, что процессор сам умеет швырять такие исключения при делении на 0, однако, в стандарте C++ такой обработки нет - ее надо сделать:

**GCC**

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <memory>

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<void(int)> handler(
        signal(SIGFPE, [](int signum) {throw std::logic_error("FPE"); }),
        [](__sighandler_t f) { signal(SIGFPE, f); });

    int i = 0;

    cin >> i;  // what if someone enters zero?

    try {
        i = 5/i;
    }
    catch (std::logic_error e) {
        std::cerr << e.what();
    }
}
```

**Visual C++**

```
#include <eh.h>
#include <memory>

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<void(unsigned, EXCEPTION_POINTERS*)> handler(
        _set_se_translator([](unsigned u, EXCEPTION_POINTERS* p) {
            switch(u) {
                case FLT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO:
                    throw std::logic_error("Divide by zero");
                ...
                default:
                    throw std::logic_error("SEH exception");
            }
        }),
        [](_se_translator_function f) { _set_se_translator(f); });

    int i = 0;

    try {
        i = 5 / i;
    } catch(std::logic_error e) {
        std::cerr << e.what();
    }
}
```

[Оригинал на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25601100/5533854)

**Почему это лучше сравнения с 0 перед делением?**

- это задействует аппаратные возможности платформы по отлову ошибок
- работает быстрее (не надо делать лишних сравнений)
- гарантирует, что вы не забудете где-то сделать проверку

Comment: Зачем `shared_ptr`? Владелец указателя один (`main()`), в этом случае лучше использовать `unique_ptr` — меньше накладных расходов.

Comment: @Arhad - у вас есть два пути решения данной проблемы - пойти к автору оригинального ответа и наругать его, либо предложить правку.

Comment: Как минимум `_EXCEPTION_POINTERS` (с подчерком)...

Comment: @Harry `_EXCEPTION_POINTERS` ничего не знает о `shared_ptr` и, соответственно, не может увеличить счетчик ссылок и продлить время жизни указателя.

Comment: @Arhad А об `EXCEPTION_POINTERS` мой VC++ 2015, например, ничего не знает и знать не желает...